# Unable to Change Kubectl Context to my Google Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I've created a Google Kubernetes Engine Cluster through the Cloud Console. Now I want to connect to it using `kubectl` from my local machine.
A few weeks ago I used

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials cents-ideas --zone europe-west3-a --project cents-ideas
```

as provided by the Cloud Console.

The output after running this command is:

```
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for cents-ideas.
```

But the cluster is neither in `kubectl config get-contexts` nor set as `kubectl config current-context`. I am confused because this command used to work and did nothing different.

[image: c]

---

My `kubectl version`:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.2", GitCommit:"59603c6e503c87169aea6106f57b9f242f64df89", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-18T23:30:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.2", GitCommit:"59603c6e503c87169aea6106f57b9f242f64df89", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-18T23:22:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

and `gcloud version`

```
Google Cloud SDK 278.0.0
alpha 2020.01.24
beta 2020.01.24
bq 2.0.52
core 2020.01.24
gsutil 4.47
kubectl 2020.01.24
```

`cat ~/.kube/config`

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <LONG HASH>
    server: https://35.234.108.15
  name: gke_cents-ideas_europe-west3-a_cents-ideas
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: gke_cents-ideas_europe-west3-a_cents-ideas
    user: gke_cents-ideas_europe-west3-a_cents-ideas
  name: gke_cents-ideas_europe-west3-a_cents-ideas
current-context: gke_cents-ideas_europe-west3-a_cents-ideas
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: gke_cents-ideas_europe-west3-a_cents-ideas
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        access-token: <SOME TOKEN>
        cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json
        cmd-path: /snap/google-cloud-sdk/115/bin/gcloud
        expiry: "2020-02-02T09:45:19Z"
        expiry-key: '{.credential.token_expiry}'
        token-key: '{.credential.access_token}'
      name: gcp
```

Output of `kubectl get nodes`

```
NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
flolubuntu   Ready    <none>   42d   v1.17.2
```

Comment: can you run `cat ~/.kube/config`? what's the output?

Comment: I've added it :)

Comment: looks fine to me.. whats's the `kubectl get nodes` output ?

Comment: I've added it... but i just returns my machine... when it used to work a few weeks ago it showed the gke nodes

Comment: Just to check, can you pls run `echo $KUBECONFIG`

Comment: the output is an empty line

Comment: So odd. So if you do (and this shouldn't make a difference): `KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config kubectl get nodes` ... Still no joy?

Comment: still only returns my local machine

Comment: maybe i should reinstall kubectl?

Comment: I don't think that will help, but obviously easy thing to try ...

Comment: My guess is somehow your kubectl config is poiniting to the wrong cluster. Try to delete the file and re-run `gcloud container clusters get-credentials...`

Comment: still not added the context

Comment: I found the issue (see my answer). But thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had `microk8s` installed. Removing it and instead installing `snap install kubectl` fixed my issue.

Comment: Make sense, glad you find the issue